# XSS PoC for JSON

Tags: xss, json

When I am requesting for a password reset, it's making  a request like this ->

```
{"eval":"uiFormNotify('messageDiv', 'info', 'msg.email_reset_to_existing', 10);Metronic.unblockUI('#forgotPwdForm');$('#forgotPwdForm').html($.t('msg.may_close'));"}
```

And after replacing a `msg.may_close` with xss payload it's actually executing.
`may_close` is a string variable initialized in .json

So can anyone suggest me how can I make a valid PoC for this?

Comment: I'm confused, if you can execute a payload, then you have your PoC right there.

Comment: Yeah I’m with @schroeder. If your audience is more skeptical, prove the payload is executing on the target’s domain (i.e., “alert(document.domain)”). But that’s about all you’d need to do.

Comment: payload is executing ,but its a msg from websockets not a server request so it does not contain any headers and we cant even sent that to repeater in burpsuit so I am confused because I cant see any way to create exploit for it.